# ASP.Net AutoCompleteExtender VB WebMethod not firing - why?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, autocompleteextender, webmethod

Definitely at my wits end here.  This should be simple.  In a page to create new user accounts, we have a database with a little of allowable users.  To streamline getting the Email address of the new user correct, we want to use an AutoComplete extended textbox.

Now I know that WebMethods are working because I have a cascading-drop-down tied to web methods in another page.

As I'm just starting on this page, the code is simple.

The page itself:

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server"/>
<p></p> Please enter new user's Email: 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" runat="server" />
<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="autUser" TargetControlID="txtUser" 
        ServiceMethod="ScanGALUsers" ServicePath="~/AutoScan.asmx"
        MinimumPrefixLength="3" CompletionSetCount="150" /> <p></p>
```

The .asmx file is simple:

```
<%@ WebService Language="VB" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/VB_Code/AutoScan.vb" Class="AutoScan" %>
```

The WebMethod:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Public Class AutoScan
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

   <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function ScanGALUsers(ByVal strPrefix As String, ByVal intMaxCount As Integer) As String()
        Dim arlResults As New ArrayList
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim colParameters As New SortedList
        SysDA.LogDebug("ScanGALUsers called with parameters: " & strPrefix & " and count of " & intMaxCount.ToString)
        ... Deleted for brevity ...
        If intCount > 0 Then
            Dim arrResults(intCount - 1) As String
            arrResults = arlResults.ToArray(GetType(System.String))
            Return arrResults
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

I'm not even getting to the LogDebug statement.  I've used all the same boilerplate code (Inherits, the 'WebService' tags, etc) that worked in the other WebMethod with the appropriate changes to the Class name but this really has me stumped.

What am I missing that I'm not even making it to the method?

Comment: Can you check Fiddler (or FireBug / other alternatives) and see if there is an actual call being done to the server?

Comment: Very restrictive environment here (military base).  Can't install tools that aren't approved.  It doesn't appear to be making the call as I set a breakpoint in the method and it never gets there.  (Doing the same in a different WebMethod *does* work)

Comment: It is likely that the calls the asmx-file are actually being done, but that the result to the call is not getting through, either resulting in a 404 or 500. If I were you I'd check if the calls are happening, and if they are, what their http response codes are. 

Edit: Is Chrome approved? It has similar functionality. 
Something that's able to see traffic between client & server is really handy with issues like these.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can fire the service *manually* in the browser.

Comment: Looking in the System Even Viewer, I get a warnign message saying "Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/ScanGALUsers'."  I tried changing the signature of the web method's 2nd parameter from an integer to a string just to see if that was it and still nothing.  I get my Debug message when I go into the webmethod manually with the browser.  Verry irritating and puzzling.

Comment: The following seems to be related and may be of help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1459560.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve this issue? Have you tried removing `Shared` from your WebService declaration? This has worked for me before (and I don't know why!).

Comment: Yeah - I boiled down the webservice to just return a few hard-coded entries, removed "Shared" and it *still* didn't fire.  I'd blame it on the security policies here and some environment setting that I can't control except that *other* webservices work...  *Very* frustrating - but thanks for the idea.